# .net ReportViewer - Object reference not set to an instance of an object? ReportError

Tags: c#, debugging, reportviewer

[image]

Where can I catch the error that is displayed in the report viewer, since this isn't code generated by me?
Particularly, I want to find out which Object is not set to an instance.

Comment: check your data loading function and the column of your report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the .aspx page, add an event handler OnReportError to the ReportViewer element:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" style="margin-top: 0px" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="817px" Height="554px"
OnReportError="ReportErrorEventHandler">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="App_Code\Session_subclasses\CustomerPortal\SGTSAssetCatalog.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" 
                Name="DataSet1" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

In the .aspx.cs page add a Method to handle the event. The event contains the Exception under e.Exception:

```
public void ReportErrorEventHandler(Object sender, ReportErrorEventArgs e)
{
    throw e.Exception;
}
```

After following the path of InnerExceptions it turned out for me, that the connection string specified in the DataSet existed in my development environment, but not in the test environment... took long enough to get to the bottom of this simple issue -.-

Answer (score 0):

The above might help. Try t oadd the event ReportViewer.ReportError Event.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.reporterror(v=vs.100).aspx